# Stripe ios what is the different between paymentContext and paymentMethodViewController

Tags: ios, stripe-payments

I am not working on an iOS app that uses stripe. I want to simply create a view controller that can collects user card information and saved to users customer id which I created when they register account for my app. But I want to know should I use `paymentMethodViewController` or `STPPaymentContext` to create the standard UI made by Stripe. On Stripe website, they have a demo iOS app called RocketRide, I downloaded the app and read through each line. This app only uses `STPPaymentContext` but it has all the UI including `selectPaymentMethod` and add the card. So can anyone tell me which one should I use and how to use them specifically, thank you!
[You can see RocketRide's UI at the top of this link](https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios)

Answer (score 0):

`STPPaymentContext` is an end-to-end class that handles the full checkout process, by collecting the user's payment, shipping and billing details. It does this by combining together several other components from the Stripe SDK, including `STPPaymentMethodsViewController`, which handles only presenting a set of payment methods to the user and adding more.

Basically the difference is that `STPPaymentContext` is a full checkout flow integration, while `STPPaymentMethodsViewController` is a component that is used in part of that flow. It is possible to build your own flow by combining the SDK elements yourself, and in that case you would directly use `STPPaymentMethodsViewController`. For your use case though, it sounds like `STPPaymentContext` is the better option, it is easier to use in general.

[0] - https://stripe.github.io/stripe-ios/docs/Classes/STPPaymentContext.html 
[1] - https://stripe.github.io/stripe-ios/docs/Classes/STPPaymentMethodsViewController.html